# Showing a sequence is Cauchy; loss of generality?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The exercise is as follows;

> Show that the sequence $$(a_n) = \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n \in \Bbb N}$$
>   is a Cauchy Sequence.

**Solution:** Let $m > n.$ Since we are trying to show that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, we must have that $$\lvert a_m  - a_n\rvert < \varepsilon$$

for $m > n > N.$  We also have that $$\left|\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ So, given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $N \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ and then we have that $\lvert a_m  - a_n\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $m > n > N$.

Is this correct? That is, is it fine to impose the condition that $m >n $ without losing generality?

Comment: It looks just fine to me, and of course you can assume WLOG that $\;m>n\;$ .

Comment: If you mean to use the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\leq\frac{1}{m}$, that isn't right. That said, a small adaptation in your proof makes it right,; and the WLOG assumption is fine too.

Comment: $1/\sqrt m>1/m$ for $m\ge 2$.

Comment: I actually just have $N \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ right?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  If you want to get rid of any appearance of losing generality, you can use the estimate
$$
{1 \over \sqrt{m}} + {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \leq { 2 \over \sqrt{\min(m, n)} }.
$$

Comment: You need $\lvert a_{n+p}  - a_n\rvert < \varepsilon$ so WLOG you can do $m\gt n$.